# jquery filedownload, cancel download while is preparing

Tags: jquery

I use jquery.filedownload for a file that takes times to be created.

Is there a way/command for cancelling/stop the download?

like

```
var myDownload = $.fileDownload(myUrl, { ...

myDownload.stop();
```

---

[jquery.filedownload](https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload/blob/master/src/Scripts/jquery.fileDownload.js)

---

for cross browsing, the plugin use iframe instead of ajax. I search a way to cancel the download without changing the plugin. instead I will return the iframe and call stop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the abort command:

```
var request = $.ajax({ url...
});

//kill the request
request.abort();
```

Comment: I dont use ajax, but a plugin jquery. I add the link in the post description.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. I have modified a bit jquery.filedownload library. Here is a fork - 
https://github.com/Zowiks/jquery.fileDownload/blob/c0f55bf81727ae6b755bd3b42a78dc6977b55efb/src/Scripts/jquery.fileDownload.js

now you can use `abort()` function like in all `$.ajax` requests.

Sample:

```
var myDownload = $.fileDownload(myUrl, { ...
myDownload.abort();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the latest code for the plugin (v 1.4.5). They seem to have added abort method.